# How to type useState for files?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

```
const [files, setFiles] = useState([])  
const filesHandler = (e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
     e.preventDefault()
     setFiles(e.target.files)
}
```

input:

```
<input
     id="file" type="file"
     multiple={true} 
     onChange={e => filesHandler(e)}
/>
```

*Argument of type 'FileList | null' is not assignable to parameter of type 'SetStateAction<never[]>'.   Type 'null' is not assignable to type 'SetStateAction<never[]>'.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using `vscode` is already trying to say the type of the multiple file

Argument of type HERE--->`'FileList | null'` is not assignable to parameter of type 'SetStateAction<never[]>'.   Type 'null' is not assignable to type 'SetStateAction<never[]>'.

```
const [files, setFiles] = React.useState<FileList | null>();
```